# create whmcs domain registrar module to sell domains with the tld of my country

Tags: dns, whmcs

Hi everyone
I have a site with whmcs and i want to sell domains with the tld of my county that is .al and i've searched the web for this but all told me that i need to create a domain registrar module.
I'v downloaded the template from the whmcs site but i don't know how to use it.Does anyone have any idea how can i achieve this.

```
   <?php

    function template_getConfigArray() {
$configarray = array(
 "Username" => array( "Type" => "text", "Size" => "20", "Description" => "Enter your username here", ),
 "Password" => array( "Type" => "password", "Size" => "20", "Description" => "Enter your password here", ),
 "TestMode" => array( "Type" => "yesno", ),
);
return $configarray;
    }

    function template_GetNameservers($params) {
$username = $params["Username"];
$password = $params["Password"];
$testmode = $params["TestMode"];
$tld = $params["tld"];
$sld = $params["sld"];
# Put your code to get the nameservers here and return the values below
$values["ns1"] = $nameserver1;
$values["ns2"] = $nameserver2;
$values["ns3"] = $nameserver3;
$values["ns4"] = $nameserver4;
# If error, return the error message in the value below
$values["error"] = $error;
return $values;
    }

    function template_SaveNameservers($params) {
$username = $params["Username"];
$password = $params["Password"];
$testmode = $params["TestMode"];
$tld = $params["tld"];
$sld = $params["sld"];
$nameserver1 = $params["ns1"];
$nameserver2 = $params["ns2"];
$nameserver3 = $params["ns3"];
$nameserver4 = $params["ns4"];
# Put your code to save the nameservers here
# If error, return the error message in the value below
$values["error"] = $error;
return $values;
    }

    function template_GetRegistrarLock($params) {
$username = $params["Username"];
$password = $params["Password"];
$testmode = $params["TestMode"];
$tld = $params["tld"];
$sld = $params["sld"];
# Put your code to get the lock status here
if ($lock=="1") {
    $lockstatus="locked";
} else {
    $lockstatus="unlocked";
}
return $lockstatus;
   }

    function template_SaveRegistrarLock($params) {
$username = $params["Username"];
$password = $params["Password"];
$testmode = $params["TestMode"];
$tld = $params["tld"];
$sld = $params["sld"];
if ($params["lockenabled"]) {
    $lockstatus="locked";
} else {
    $lockstatus="unlocked";
}
# Put your code to save the registrar lock here
# If error, return the error message in the value below
$values["error"] = $Enom->Values["Err1"];
return $values;
   }
```

This is a part of the code from the module template.

Answer (score 0):

Well the first step would be determining which registrar you are going to use to register your domains. There are quite a few that already have modules pre-built and included in WHMCS. You can see the list [here](http://docs.whmcs.com/Domain_Registrars).

If you are using a registrar that does not already have a pre-built module in WHMCS, then you will need to create your own. The template you downloaded has all of the supported functions in WHMCS. Before you roll out your own module however, you will want to see if your registrar has an API. If they do not then building the module for WHMCS is pointless. If they do, read through their documentation. Once you are familiar with the registrar's functionality, then it's just a matter of connecting the dots between the WHMCS template you downloaded and the registrar's API.

Best of luck!